# Select One Dataset From List To Perform Rest Analysis Using R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

The below code help to select multiple values in different columns
    through checkboxes in shiny app and selected data display in the right 
    panel. I wanted to perform the same action on any selected dataset from the
    list i.e. I have two sample data, one should be able to select one dataset 
    from drop down menu and the selected sample data (weekly or monthly)
    would be available in right panel to perform  action on via check boxes. 
    Many Thanks for the help in advance

```
---Sample_wkly   
MO_ID   DrugType    Customer    Revenue DrugClass
W1  Drug 1  Manufacturer5   12765   ART
W2  Drug 2  Manufacturer4   41528   II
W3  Drug 3  Manufacturer3   4204    NNRTI
W4  Drug 4  Manufacturer2   57222   PI
W5  Drug 5  Manufacturer1   3121    STR
W6  Drug 1  Manufacturer5   11917   NNRTI
W7  Drug 2  Manufacturer4   2059    PI
W8  Drug 3  Manufacturer3   11116   STR
W9  Drug 4  Manufacturer2   3815    NNRTI
W10 Drug 5  Manufacturer1   21071   PI
W11 Drug 1  Manufacturer5   9830    STR
W12 Drug 2  Manufacturer4   152061  NNRTI
W13 Drug 3  Manufacturer3   7215    PI
W14 Drug 4  Manufacturer2   10508   STR
W15 Drug 5  Manufacturer1   22802   ART
W16 Drug 1  Manufacturer5   7486    II
W17 Drug 2  Manufacturer4   13627   NNRTI
W18 Drug 3  Manufacturer3   27594   PI
W19 Drug 4  Manufacturer2   31728   STR
W20 Drug 5  Manufacturer1   12711   NNRTI
W21 Drug 1  Manufacturer3   1241    PI

Sample_mthly
MO_ID   DrugType    Customer    Revenue DrugClass
Jan-00  Drug 1  Manufacturer5   12765   ART
Feb-01  Drug 2  Manufacturer4   41528   II
Mar-02  Drug 3  Manufacturer3   4204    NNRTI
Apr-03  Drug 4  Manufacturer2   57222   PI
May-04  Drug 5  Manufacturer1   3121    STR
Jun-05  Drug 1  Manufacturer5   11917   NNRTI
Jul-06  Drug 2  Manufacturer4   2059    PI
Aug-07  Drug 3  Manufacturer3   11116   STR
Sep-08  Drug 4  Manufacturer2   3815    NNRTI
Oct-09  Drug 5  Manufacturer1   21071   PI
Nov-10  Drug 1  Manufacturer5   9830    STR
Dec-11  Drug 2  Manufacturer4   152061  NNRTI
Jan-12  Drug 3  Manufacturer3   7215    PI

Source Code-
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

#############################
# Importing Data
cDat <- read.table(file = "data/sample_wkly.csv", sep = ",",  header = 
                 TRUE, row.names = NULL)
cDat1 <- read.table(file = "data/sample_mthly.csv", sep = ",",  header = 
                 TRUE, row.names = NULL)
############################

###### Preparing list for Checkbox & Change rownames
#campaigns_list <- unique(cDat$MANUFACTURER)

MANUFACTURER_list <- unique(cDat$MANUFACTURER)
DrugClass_list <- unique(cDat$DrugClass)
DrugType_list <- unique(cDat$DrugType)
columns <- names(cDat)
####################### Server.R##########
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filteredData <- reactive({ switch(input$Data,
                                "Weekly" = cDat,
                                "Monthly" = cDat1)
    cDat %>% filter(MANUFACTURER %in% input$campaign &
                      DrugClass %in% input$campaign1 &
                      DrugType %in% input$campaign2 )
  })


  selectedData <- reactive({

    filteredData() %>% 
      select_(.dots = input$columns)
  })
  output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({
    selectedData()
  })
}


####################### UI.R ##############
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Example"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( selectInput("Data", "Choose data:", 
                              choices =  c("Weekly","Monthly"), 
selected =         "Weekly"),
      checkboxGroupInput('campaign', 'Manufacturer',
                     MANUFACTURER_list,
                     selected = MANUFACTURER_list),
  checkboxGroupInput('campaign1', 'DrugClass',
                     DrugClass_list,
                     selected = DrugClass_list),
  checkboxGroupInput('campaign2', 'DrugType',
                     DrugType_list,
                     selected = DrugType_list),
  checkboxGroupInput('columns', 'Columns',
                     columns,
                     selected = columns)
    ),


    ##### Show data in Main Panel  
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
  dataTableOutput('mytable1'))
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assigning Packages
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)


header <- dashboardHeader(


#######################################################################################
# Importing Data
#######################################################################################
cDat <- read.table(file = "data/sample_wkly.csv", sep = ",",  header = 
                 TRUE, row.names = NULL)
cDat1 <- read.table(file = "data/sample_mthly.csv", sep = ",",  header = 
                 TRUE, row.names = NULL)

data_sets <- c("cDat", "cDat1")
#######################################################################################
###### Preparing list for Checkbox & Change rownames
MANUFACTURER_list <- unique(cDat$MANUFACTURER)
DrugClass_list <- unique(cDat$DrugClass)
DrugType_list <- unique(cDat$DrugType)
columns <- names(cDat)

####################### Server.R##########
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  filteredData <- reactive({  if(is.null(input$dataset))
    return()
    cDat <- get(input$dataset)
    cDat %>% filter(MANUFACTURER %in% input$campaign |
                  DrugClass %in% input$campaign1 |
                  DrugType %in% input$campaign2 )
  })


  selectedData <- reactive({

    filteredData() %>% 
      select_(.dots = input$columns)
  })
  output$mytable1 <- renderDataTable({

    selectedData()

  })
}

####################### UI.R ##############
ui <- fluidPage(
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Forecasting Engine"),
  # Sidebar with a slider input for the number of bins
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel( 
   checkboxGroupInput('campaign', 'Manufacturer',
                     MANUFACTURER_list,
                     selected = MANUFACTURER_list),
  checkboxGroupInput('campaign1', 'DrugClass',
                     DrugClass_list,
                     selected = DrugClass_list),
  checkboxGroupInput('campaign2', 'DrugType',
                     DrugType_list,
                     selected = DrugType_list),
  checkboxGroupInput('columns', 'Columns',
                     columns,
                     selected = columns),
  selectInput("dataset", "Select Frequency", as.list(data_sets))
    ),


    ##### Show data in Main Panel  
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      dataTableOutput('mytable1'))
  )
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```